# how to add interface in python, with pygame

Tags: python, interface, pygame

Help! I am new to programming! I am trying to make a monopoly game. My program so far creates player and card objects, these objects have some values stored.

I am trying to use pygame to implement some kind of animations and create a menu bar that pops up on the pygame screen, but I don't know how to get started. So far all I have is a pygame background screen, I want to know how I can place a small rectangle on the pygame screen given position, depending on the players object's position value. I need to know how I can have all that code I have written just for the game logic, and have it run along side with this pygame stuff.

I really need to know how to get started. If anyone is willing to spend some time with me, to get me going in the right direction, I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [pygame tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials) and [Invent Your Own Computer Games With Python](http://inventwithpython.com/chapters/)

Answer (score 1):

Reading over some [pygame tutorials](http://rene.f0o.com/mywiki/PythonGameProgramming) will certainly help.

The flow of your program will eventually look something like this:

```
# This is intentionally simplified pseudocode, but at the bottom-most level most
#    simple games have a similar structure to this.

#Construct your game objects
players = [Player(args) for n in range(num_players)]
cards = loadCards()   #or however you load your cards (files,database,etc)
board = Board()

#initialize your display context
pygame_screen.init()  #or whatever is the correct syntax for Pygame

# Main game loop
while 1:
    check_inputs()    #get key/mouse input inputs for this frame
    handle_inputs()    #handle each input that has occurred during this frame
    update_gamestate()    #update the state on the game (who's turn, etc)
    update_display()    #update pygame window graphics (draw stuff, flip display)

cleanup()
```

As for the details on how to draw rectangles and whatnot, you should read about the various draw functions [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)